# Converting a date to text in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data set that includes values as text such as "March 2016".

Now I have written the following code to replicate this in my report sheet:

```
DataFin.Range("E9:E9") = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0)
DataFin.Range("E9:E9").Text = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "mmmm yyyy")
```

It has the correct format, but when I click on the cell the value states "3/1/2016" instead of "March 2016".

Any ideas how I can change the underlying value to "March 2016"

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: It is not a formatting issue, I want the cell value to be text "March 2016" not "3/1/2016.

Comment: See my posted answer for a more complete explanation

Comment: With regard to your code above, the `Text` property of the Range object is read only. I am surprised you do not get an error.

Comment: No, didn't get a error. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must format the cell as text, and then set the value to the text value of the date you want.

For example:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim DT As Date
DT = Date

With Range("a1")
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Value = Format(DT, "mmmm yyyy")
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was after, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Documentation for Date formating : https://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba_tricks/date_format.php